# "Placing" arbitrary number of values into Python Flask request_context?

Tags: python, flask

So I have a Python Flask app such as the following: (it's actually a [Clay Flask](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clay-flask/1.1) app, but whatever):

`some_file.py`:

```
@app.route('/v1/some/route', methods=['GET'])
def some_method():
    arg1 = request.args.get('arg1', None)
    arg2 = request.args.get('arg2', None)
    header1 = request.headers.get('header1', None)
    result = my_class.method_call(arg1, arg2, header1)
```

`my_class.py`:

```
...
def method_call(self, arg1, arg2):
    # need to access header1 here
    some_other_service.make_request(arg1, arg2, header1)
```

The problem, is, I have a large number of headers, not just `header1`, that `method_call` needs to know about in its call to `some_other_service.make_request`. I could pass them all into `method_call`, or create a wrapper object that has all of the headers as attributes, but have been recommended to put the headers in the Flask/Clay `request_context`.

Here is where I'm stuck. I've read documentation on Flask and request_contexts, but am still confused. How would I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use request in your Class.

```
# from Flask import request

def method_call(self, arg1, arg2):
    # need to access header1 here
    foo = request.headers.get('foo')
    bar = request.headers.get('bar')
    some_other_service.make_request(arg1, arg2, header1)
```